# Meanings and pronunciation of 截

Tags: meaning

What are all meanings of 截? as in 截拳道?

Is it pronounced "Jeet" or "Jee"?

---

I'm interested in the word "jeet" and how it may be used.

Comment: A dictionary would've helped you there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. What are all meanings of 截?**

It has the following meanings according to [Xinhua Dictionary online](http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/10849.html):

- 割断，弄断：截断。截开。截取。截面。(to cut off, to truncate)
- 量词，段：一截儿木头。 (measure word: a section, a chunk)
- 阻拦：截住他。截留。截击。截获。(to intercept, to obstruct)
- 到一定期限停止：截止。 (cut-off point, deadline)

**2. (What's the meaning) as in 截拳道?**

In 截拳道, 截 means 'to intercept'. The spirit of 截拳道 is to 'intercept' the opponent's intention/omens of attack, and counter the attack accordingly. There is more information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeet_Kune_Do#Principles):

> JKD teaches that the best defence is a strong offence, hence the principle of an "intercepting fist". For a person to attack another hand-to-hand, the attacker must approach the target. This provides an opportunity for the attacked person to "intercept" the attacking movement. The principle of interception may be applied to more than intercepting physical attacks. Non-verbal cues (subtle movements that an opponent may be unaware of) may be perceived or "intercepted", and thus be used to one's advantage.

**3. Is it pronounced "Jeet" or "Jee"?**

`截` is pronunced as `jie2` in Mandarin and `zit6` in Cantonese.

Jeet/Jee are non-standard transliterations from Cantonese to English.

**4. I'm interested in the word "jeet" and how it may be used.**

If you're talking about the English word, I don't think there are widely-known usages other than in 'Jeet Kune Do'.

Comment: what is "2" in "jie2"?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus It's [tone number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_number). The most formal way to mark tones in Pinyin is to use diacritics, i.e. `jié`. However, diacritics are difficult to input or even unavailable (e.g. on typewriters), the [numeric tone marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin#Numerals_in_place_of_tone_marks) are commonly used as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

截” should be pronounced as “ jie2”（second tone）, it has three meanings:
1. cut; sever:
  截成两段（cut in two）
  He cut the sugarcane into several pieces.
  他把甘蔗截成几节。
2. stop; check; stem; intercept:
  截流（dam a river）
3. （measure word)section; chunk; length:
half a piece of chalk;
半截粉笔
a section of a log;
一截木头

So the “截” of “截拳道” means “ to stop”.

Comment: why do I hear 't' in the pronunciation of google translate: http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/zh-TW/%E6%88%AA%E6%8B%B3%E9%81%93 ?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus I can understand why you are mishearing. The pronunciation is jiéquándào (pinyin) = [tɕjɛ tɕʰyɛn tɑʊ] (IPA) = "jee-a choo-en dao" (how an american might approximate it by spelling). You are presumably hearing the beginning of the next syllable (quán ~ "choo-en") as a "t".

Answer (score 0):

In Mandarin, the character `截` is pronounced jié. In Cantonese, zit6. The character has a few related meanings and is used in a number of words. [From zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/622A.htm):

1. `割断`，`弄断` = sever, cut off, break

   - `截断` = cut off, block
   - `截开` = cut open
   - `截取` = cut out, intercept
   - `截面` = cross-section
2. `(量词) 段` = a measure word, meaning a 'section' or a 'length'

   - `一截儿木头` = a length/section of wood
3. `阻拦` = stop, obstruct

   - `截住他` = stopped him, intercepted him
   - `截留` = trap, retain
   - `截击` = intercept, volley (tennis)
   - `截获` = intercept and/or capture
4. `到一定期限停止` = stop (at a certain time)

   - `截止` = close, stop (in word for expiration date, deadline, etc.)

#### TL;DR

**It means to cut, sever, or block**

Comment: The spirit of 截拳道 is to intercept and counter attack instead of block (defense), so the short summary could be misleading for the question.